# Search with date range in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a db table  `dateprices`

`id|tour_id|start|end|price`

I want to get all the price of the tour starting and ending between the dates i.e. `2017-06-20` and `2017-07-11`

I have written following query but it is returning an empty collection:

```
$dates = DatePrice::where('tour_id','=',$request->product_id)
  ->where('start', 'like', '%'.$request->start.'%')
  ->where('end', 'like', '%'.$request->end.'%')
  ->get();
```

Is there something wrong with my query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `whereBetween()` function like so:

```
$dates = DatePrice::where('tour_id','=',$request->product_id)
    ->whereBetween('start', array('2017-06-20', '2017-07-11'))
    ->whereBetween('end', array('2017-06-20', '2017-07-11'))
    ->get();
```

Comment: The query is giving me all rows of the table even if I take today's date as start and tomorrow's date as end date.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below query,

If there is a single condition then you can user `whereBetween()`.
If you would like to add more condition, you can use `orWhereBetween()`.

```
$dates = DatePrice::where('tour_id','=',$request->product_id)
  ->whereBetween('start', 'like', '%'.$request->start.'%')
  ->orWhereBetween('end', 'like', '%'.$request->end.'%')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search by specifying the name of the column (dates) like so;

```
$dates = DatePrice::where('tour_id','=',$request->product_id)
         ->whereBetween('date', array($request->from_date, $request->to_date))
         ->get();
```